# sqlalchemy, insert with try except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, insert, pymysql

I have a query that I intend to insert with a try-except block, so that I can ignore all the queries that fail a certain constraint i.e. `IntegrityError`.

```
with sql_engine.begin() as cn:
        sql = """INSERT INTO table1 (m_id, pick_on)
                    SELECT t.m_id, t.pick_on
                    FROM temp_table t
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                        (SELECT 1 FROM table1 f
                        WHERE (t.m_id = f.m_id
                        OR  (t.m_id IS NULL AND f.m_id IS NULL))
                        AND t.pick_on = f.pick_on)"""
        try:
            cn.execute(sql)
        except:
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            print(sql)
            pass
```

but this does not insert all the records to `table1`. why?

Comment: Ah, hey Any help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including connection URI, table DDL, and sample data showing which rows get skipped that should actually be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy starts MySQL commands but there is no try-except block on MySQL itself. MySQL just stops when it can't execute a command and this cannot be overulled by the python except route.